# Browser Question

Tags: browser

Firefox has turned out to be monumentally unstable on my Ubuntu laptop. On the other hand, Opera seems quite stable. However, I must use Terminal to launch Opera. When I click on the Opera icon in the dock, it just seems to beat like a heart 5 or 6 times, but doesn't launch. In Terminal, I simply type in "opera." How can I make the Opera icon in my dock work?

Comment: It is not really a browser question. I suggest you file a bug report against firefox for the firefox problem and opera for the opera problem. I also suggest chromium rather then opera.

Comment: Do you have a lot of extensions installed in Firefox? If so, disable them all and see if FF runs better. If so, re-enable one at a time until you find the bad apple. For Opera, when you launch it from terminal, does a 2nd Opera icon appear in the launcher?